# NLog filename per thread

Tags: nlog

I'm trying to create log filename dynamically using NLog (.NET Framework 4.8). Basically, I would like unique filename created every time new thread is fired. I got it somewhat working with the following sections:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile" header="${machinename}${newline}${threadid}${newline}"
            fileName="${mdc:logFolder}\${date:format=yyyyMMdd}\log_${activityid}.txt" layout="${date}|${activityid}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}"
            footer="${newline}Finished at: ${date}"/>

<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="ownFile" />
```

When thread is started, it sets the logFolder using `MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set` and sets the `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId`. But there is one problem. The footer part is only written when FileTarget is disposed, which I believe then closes all file appenders cached inside FileTarget.

Is there a way for me to manually close the internal file appender for dynamic file? What I want is when thread is done with its processing is to close the dynamic log file.

I also have another approach working where I add new FileTarget when thread starts and the remove it when thread is finished. It does work, but I would prefer config file solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using to Footer-Layout for this situation. Then I would probably just have the thread write a final LogEvent that signals that it has completed.

Comment: I see. That's a much better solution. I was trying to follow header/footer logic, but it seems like while header is created when file is created, footer is created when file target closes or gets disposed.

Comment: Yes the header/footer logic is mostly for the entire application lifetime. Not for log-files that are only active for a "short" lifetime.